# Why does only part of my data print when I filter using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

My code is below:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(attri = c(1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
                                   2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, 4, 5, 6,
                                   7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
                         type = c(10, 14, 19, 25, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
                                  37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,43, 44, 49, 
                                  55, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
                                  60, 61, 62, 60, 64, 69, 75, 72, 73, 74, 
                                  75, 76, 77, 78, 79))
    i <- 1:3
    df2 <- dplyr::filter(df1, attri==i)
    View(df2)
```

When I run this, it outputs the following data frame:

```
     attri type
1      1   10
2      1   25
3      1   34
4      1   37
5      2   38
6      2   41
7      2   44
8      2   52
9      3   53
10     3   56
11     3   59
12     3   62
```

How do I view the entire data set that satisfies the filter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try `df2 <- dplyr::filter(df1, attri %in% i)` I think you're running into an [argument recycling](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules) issue. Examine the warning message when running `filter(df1[-1,], attri == i)`

Answer (score 0):

You want `attri %in% i` not `attri == i`.

R "recycles" vectors if one is shorter than the other.  For example, suppose you want to add two vectors, say x=c(1,2,3) and y=c(5), and so you write the code x+y.  R recycles the shorter vector (y) until is the same length as the longer vector (x) and then it adds these vectors element-wise.  So x+y is really (1, 2, 3) + (5, 5, 5) = (6, 7, 8).

Your test (`attri == i`) is comparing the `attri` vector to the vector (1, 2, 3). Because the second vector is shorter than the first, it is recycled to become (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, ...) until it is the same length as `attri`.  The then test `==` checks for equality element-wise.

By using `attri %in% i` you are asking R if each element of `attri` is either 1, 2, or 3.  This will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE that is the same length as `attri`. `filter()` then selects the rows of `df1` where the test is TRUE.  This is what you want.